# Problem attempting running React Native App into Physical Phone

Tags: android, react-native

I had try running a React Native App (NOT EXPO) in my phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 PRO)

I got these errors -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVnaE.png

I follow all steps into https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started in section **React Native CLI Quickstart**

I've also Enable **USB DEBUGGING** in my Phone, add Android studio to path, but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your installation of java. It seems that it simply can not find the directory you have declared for your java 8 Development Kit. The path you have declared is for java Runtime Environment. If you can not download the jdk from https://www.java.com/ES/download/ or it needs for you to sign up and you do not wish to do that, openJDK does exist as an alternative and you can use that instead.

Comment: Yup, I've found that a few minutes ago, I didn't run cmd as admin, also I have install java well now, It's compiling now, hope for no errors again xd